# Adding messaging to cart based on Brand and Ship-to State

Tags: magento-1.7

I am not very proficient at PHP and I am faced with a situation where if a specific brand is shipping to a specific state a message need to appear at the first stage of checkout. I am working in Theme/app/design/frontend/onecall/default/template/checkout and I have been successful at pulling back the brand, but not the 'region_id'

I am using this to call in the manufacturer

```
<?php
$cartItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
          ->getQuote()
          ->getAllItems();
    foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
        $brand = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
        echo $ean;
    }
    ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The shipping address is only defined on the 2nd step of checkout. So no way to pull it at 1st.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for in the second step? If so, that would probably be an acceptable solution for my vendor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only this code on the 3rd+ step of the checkout (Shipping Method) when the shipping address is selected and saved:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getRegionId();
```